# An integral for calculating force between a charged ring and a charged point on 2D plane

Tags: integration

Problem：

Solve the following integral so I get a force function F :
$$
F\left(q_{10},q_{20},r_{10},d_{10}\right)=q_{10}q_{20}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{d_{10}-r_{10}\cos\left(t\right)}{\left(\left(r_{10}\cos\left(t\right)-d_{10}\right)^{2}+\left(r_{10}\sin\left(t\right)\right)^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}dt
$$
with q10 be charge of ring, q20 charge of point, r10 be radius of ring, d10 be distance between point and center of ring.

Context: I originally submitted this question on physics stack exchange and got no answer, probably this is too mathematical. So for more physical context: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/700251/calculate-force-between-point-of-charge-c-and-a-ring-of-charge-c-forces